# Realtime auction site - auction stauts (Active/Ended)-trigger DB event when auction closing time reached

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, triggers, real-time

I am developing an online auction site in asp.net and sql server.

How do I make the Auction status column as Inactive(false) as soon as closing date time reaches and do some other computation as well based on this changed status.

One possible solution I tried is using computed column on Status based on ClosingTime, but that works only when we do DDL operation on DB and not automatically.

Another possible solution is to write a Windows Service application that would Check DB in frequent time interval(every 5 min or so) and do the job, but this will not be a real-time solution and could cause more DB overhead. Please advise to crack this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store a boolean to indicate the status. Instead you just store an expiration time/date, and compare that to `NOW()` to determine if the auction is still active.

Comment: That's OK. Sorry if I am not able to frame my question properly. Is there any way so that we can determine all the closed auctions (with NOW()) in real time and fire a trigger or a SP to do some other work.. I mean updating other tables, notify winner and so on. My issue is real-time computation. Thoughts?

Comment: Two thoughts come to mine. The first is more reliable but might not be an option for you (depending on your site provider): create a cron task to fire every x minutes looking for this condition. The other is to tie the check into code that runs with every page visit (to first check if it's been long enough since the last check, and if so, check the conditions you're interested in).